# Check if PyObject is None

Tags: python, c++, nonetype, pyobject

I would just like to check if a `PyObject` that I have is `None`. I naively expected that any `None` `Pyobject *` returned from a function would be a NULL pointer, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

So: how do I check if a `PyObject *` of mine points to a `None` object?

I know that there are macros like `PyInt_Check(PyObject *)` around, but I couldn't find anything like `PyNone_Check`. I thought I could just check the equality between my `PyObject` and `Py_None`, but turns out I don't even know how to make equality comparisons with this library.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can just compare directly with `Py_None` using `==`:

```
if (obj == Py_None)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/none.html):

> Note that the `PyTypeObject` for `None` is not directly exposed in the
>   Python/C API. **Since `None` is a singleton, testing for object identity
>   (using `==` in C) is sufficient.** There is no `PyNone_Check()` function for
>   the same reason.