# Checking if PyObject is nullptr

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, c++11

I am using a Python C Api to fill the list containing the `PyObject*` elements and transfer it to the function in Python. Everything went very smoothly but there is one issue - transfered list in Python is containing odd `<NULL>` entries. List is containing "wanted" objects as well so it looks like it's almost-working.

This is the list preview:

```
[<NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <NULL>, <dbg.TBack object at 0x19675870>, <interface.Grid object at 0x196758B0>, <interface.Grid object at 0x196758F0>, <interface.slp object at 0x196757D0>]
```

Code I am using for filling the list in Python C API.

```
PyObject* list = PyList_New(objectsList.size());
PyObject* handle;

for (auto child : objectsList) {
    if (!child) {
        continue;
    }

    handle = child->GetHandle(); // handle = PyObject*
    if (!handle) {
        continue;
    }

    PyList_Append(list, handle);
}

return list; // push
```

I have tried adding `if(!handle)` checks but it doesn't seem to have any result in practise.

### **Question: How can I get rid of the `<NULL>` entries in my list?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in how you allocate the list. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/list.html) for `PyList_New(Py_ssize_t len)`:

> Note: If len is greater than zero, the returned list object’s items are set to NULL. Thus you cannot use abstract API functions such as `PySequence_SetItem()` or expose the object to Python code before setting all items to a real object with `PyList_SetItem()`.

I.e. it's making a list of "`len`" null pointers, rather than making an empty list with preallocated space.

The solution is either:

1. make an empty list (pass `len` 0) and keep the rest of your code the same (using `PyList_Append`), or
2. allocate the list with a size, and use `PyList_SetItem` instead of append. It you use this approach be aware that `PyList_setItem` steals a reference (so you'll have to `incref` `handle`), and that the length of the list you want only includes those objects with `getHandle()!=NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29732914/865719)

```
if (handle == Py_None) {
    continue;
}
```

Or

> int PyObject_Not(PyObject *o)
>
> Returns 0 if the object o is considered to be true, and 1 otherwise. This is equivalent to the Python expression not o. On failure, return -1.

Otherwise, maybe you could check `handle`'s string representation. According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html), you might be able to use some combination of

```
int       PyObject_Compare(PyObject *o1, PyObject *o2)
PyObject* PyObject_Repr   (PyObject *o)
```

I'm thinking something like

```
PyObject* null_str   = Py_BuildValue("null_str", "<NULL>");
PyObject* handle_str = PyObject_Repr(handle);
if (!PyObject_Compare(null_str, handle_str)) {
    continue;
}
```